# UINavigationController and UIToolBar not working in iOS 6

Tags: objective-c, ios6, uinavigationcontroller, uitoolbar

I am working on iPad app in which click event of UINavigationController and UIToolBar is working fine in iOS 5 but, It is not working in iOS 6. My code:

```
self.window.rootViewController=navCon;    
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

and in other class where i am adding right bar button to UINavigationBar

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navBtn.png"] title:@"About" target:self action:@selector(aboutClicked)];
```

I am not getting click event of rightBarButton.   Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: The method `initWithImage:title:target:action` is not a documented method of `UIBarButtonItem`... How is your code even compiling?

Answer (score 0):

UIBarButtonItem doesn't have this method. See http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIBarButtonItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Hello Alexander Merchi,                                                  i have used this method which is under "UIBarButtonItem+Image.h". Do you have any solution regarding this?

Comment: Can you provide code your category ? I think trouble in category implementation